# Tangents of $xy=(1-x-y)^2$ parallel to the $x$-axis

Tags: calculus

> At what points of the curve $xy=(1-x-y)^2$ is the tangent line parallel to the $x$-axis? Give the equation of the normal line to the curve at this point.

So far I have only solved the points of the tangent line but I don't know how to find the normal equation. Help me, please!

Comment: Please show the work you have done so far

Comment: @CharalambosKioulos I'm shocked, shocked I say at your comment.  Next thing you know, you will also be asking the OP to provide background.  If fact, it wouldn't suprise me, dogmatic as you obviously are, if you provided a link, such as https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question.

Comment: Do you know the definition of the normal line, Juxiz?

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes a picture is worth a 1000 words:

[image]

$x = 1/3$ or $x = 1$

Answer (score 0):

Equation of the curve is $xy=(1-x-y)^2$ ...(i)

As the required tangents are parallel to x-axis, the equation of the tangents will be given by

$y = k$ ...(ii)

Substituting (ii) in (i)

$kx = (1-x-k)^2 \implies x^2+k^2 + (k-2)x - 2k + 1 = 0$

$\implies (x+\frac{k-2}{2})^2 + \frac{3k^2-4k}{4} = 0$

At tangent points to curve, the equation should give only value of $x$ which means

$3k^2-4k = 0 \implies k = 0, \frac{4}{3}$ and that gives $x = 1, \frac{1}{3}$ resp.

So, tangent lines are $y = 0, y = \frac{4}{3}$ and the point of tangency $(1,0)$ and $(\frac{1}{3}, \frac{4}{3})$ resp.

The lines normal (perpendicular) to the tangent lines will be parallel to $y$ axis as the tangent lines are parallel to x-axis. Given the points of tangency, they are $x = 1, x = \frac{1}{3}$.